# I am getting the following error after installing Pint-OS and trying to run multiple alarm. I am using bochs as emulator. Any possible work around?

Tags: operating-system, bochs, pintos

```
Prototype mismatch: sub main::SIGVTALRM () vs none at /home/abhijay/pintos-os/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 934.
Constant subroutine SIGVTALRM redefined at /home/abhijay/pintos-os/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 926.
warning: can't find squish-pty, so terminal input will fail
bochs -q
========================================================================
                       Bochs x86 Emulator 2.4.6
             Build from CVS snapshot, on February 22, 2011
                   Compiled at Jun  8 2013, 05:16:04
========================================================================
00000000000i[     ] LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH not set. using compile time default '/usr/lib/bochs/plugins'
00000000000i[     ] BXSHARE not set. using compile time default '/usr/share/bochs'
00000000000i[     ] reading configuration from bochsrc.txt
00000000000e[     ] user_shortcut: old-style syntax detected
00000000000i[     ] lt_dlhandle is 0x37ed0c0
00000000000i[PLGIN] loaded plugin libbx_x.so
00000000000i[     ] installing x module as the Bochs GUI
00000000000i[     ] using log file bochsout.txt
bochs-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/bochs/plugins/libbx_x.so: undefined symbol: XpmCreatePixmapFromData
```

Any workaround for this? I have installed build-essentials and bochs simulator.

Comment: have you solved the issue ?

Comment: how have you solved this issue ?

Comment: what is the solution??

Answer (score 2):

You have to just go to the file **/home/abhijay/pintos-os/pintos/src/utils/pintos** and  comment out the whole function ***SIGVTALRM ()*** .It should work fine.